# How to input multiple ComboBox values into Access Database from Visual Studio via VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb

With the current code that I am running no errors occur, but no data gets added to the Microsoft Access DB.  It only uploads the data to the DB if 2 or less of the ComboBoxes are included in the code.  This has me very confused.  I have tried ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString, ComboBox1.SelectedItem.Text, and ComboBox1.Text and similar issues arise for all of them.  Any ideas?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public DefineDataFile As String
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection


    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
    dataFile = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX.mdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim str As String
    str = "INSERT INTO [Panels/Equipment] ([Panel/Equipment Name], [Machine Name], [Panel/Equipment #], [Type], [Functional Location], [Facility], [Category], [Lifetime Cost Savings], [Hours Per Day], [Days Per Week], [Weeks Per Year], [Description], [Environmental Condition], [Environmental Option], [Environmental Finding], [Heating/Cooling Condition], [Heating/Cooling Option], [Heating/Cooling Finding], [Wiring Condition], [Wiring Option], [Wiring Finding], [Machines ID])"
    str += "SELECT ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,[Machines].[Machines ID]"
    str += "FROM [Machines] WHERE [Machines].[Machine Name] = ? "

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Panel/Equipment Name", CType(TextBox_Name.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Machine Name", CType(TextBox_Machine.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Panel/Equipment #", CType(TextBox_PENum.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Type", CType(ComboBox_Type.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Functional Location", CType(TextBox_FunctionalLocation.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Facility", CType(TextBox_Facility.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Category", CType(ComboBox_Category.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Lifetime Cost Savings", CType(TextBox_LifetimeCostSavings.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Hours Per Day", CType(TextBox_HoursPerDay.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Days Per Week", CType(TextBox_DaysPerWeek.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Weeks Per Year", CType(TextBox_WeeksPerYear.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Priority", CType(ComboBox_Priority.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Description", CType(TextBox_Description.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Environmental Condition", CType(ComboBox_EC.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Environmental Option", CType(ComboBox_EO.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Environmental Finding", CType(ComboBox_EF.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Heating/Cooling Condition", CType(ComboBox_HCC.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Heating/Cooling Option", CType(ComboBox_HCO.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Heating/Cooling Finding", CType(ComboBox_HCF.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Wiring Condition", CType(ComboBox_WC.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Wiring Option", CType(ComboBox_WO.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Wiring Finding", CType(ComboBox_WF.SelectedItem.Text, String)))
 *  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Machine ID", CType(ComboBox_Machine.SelectedItem.ToString, String)))
   Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        MsgBox("Panel/Equipment Successfully Added")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: If it works or not, using symbols for your field names is never a good idea.  ExecuteNonQuery returns a value.  If it's more than zero, the query worked.

Comment: I don't see a parameter for your *last* "Machine Name" parameter.  OleDB does not use named parameters, but uses index positions.  I'm guessing your WHERE clause is borked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you converting a text to a string? In `CType(TextBox_Name.Text, String)` the expression `TextBox_Name.Text` is a string already. Simply write

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Panel/Equipment Name", TextBox_Name.Text))
```

For the other parameters, you must provide a value of a type which matches the type in the table column. E.g. If Machine ID in Access is a Numeric Long (32-bit), write

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Machine ID", _
    CType(ComboBox_Machine.SelectedItem, Integer))) 'Integer in VB is 32-bit
```

Also you have 21 `?` but are inserting 23 Parameters. The `Priority` parameter seems to be wrong. Since you insert the `Machine ID` directly in the INSERT, you should not add a parameter for it but instead one for `Machine Name` in the where clause.

The `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` returns an `Object`. An object does not contain a property `Text`. What kind of objects do the combo boxes contain? If you added strings, then `SelectedItem` is a string already. E.g.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Type", ComboBox_Type.SelectedItem))
```

Also I recommend you to use the project option `Strict On` in VB, as this shows you coding errors that are not shown otherwise.

Comment: As far as the parameters go, this is a block of code I have been manipulating a lot.  When I run it I have matching ? to the parameters (I should have verified before uploading on here ~ sorry). On the Combobox what would I use for those that are strings?

Comment: It depends of what type the combo box items are. If you added strings to the combobox, then the `SelectedItem` is a string already. If; however, you added  objects of say type `Person` to the combobox, then you would have to cast them to access the right proprty. E.g. `DirectCast(ComboBox_Person.SelectedItem, Person).Name`.

Comment: This helps lots.  Thank you!